# Is there an XML file editor for Linux with grid view support?

Tags: xml, gui, editors

I have been using [Altova XML Editor](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/) on Windows for a long time.  It has a wonderful feature that lets you view XML files in "grid view." This makes life easy when reading very complex XML. My question is, is there an XML editor available on Linux with a similar feature?

**EDIT**:
I am looking for some free alternative. Following is an example of grid view:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'grid view'?

Answer (score 2):

It's not free, but [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) has this feature, and runs on all three major platforms.  (It's Java-based.)  They have a [screencast demo of the feature](http://www.oxygenxml.com/demo/GridEditor/GridEditor.html).

You can get oXygen in both a standalone version and one that runs in Eclipse, which is nice since you may already be using Eclipse for developing the parts of the system that consume or produce the XML.